# How to set types of an object before it's initialized?

Tags: typescript

I have `sprites` object that's being passed down to a component. Initially it's an empty object but its parent component makes a call an rest endpoint to populate this `sprites` object. 
What's the best way to handle this?

Do I need to make `sprites` prop optional? Below is the code...

```
type SpriteProps = {
 sprites: {}
 name: string
 loading: boolean
}

const Sprite = ({ sprites = {}, name, loading }: SpriteProps) => {
```

Thank you!!

Comment: What is the issue? [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=34&pln=7&pc=41#code/C4TwDgpgBAymBOBLYEAK8D2YDOUC8UA3gFBTYLITYBcUA8gEYBWEAxsKQHYCGAthLWzAknAOakANhm4ATRGNoMMGCRG6diAX2LFWGTkNgUU+KAApCZY1QA0UHvztTZ80VE204SFOizYAlPgAfEQ67jpAA) seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible. When you define a type on an interface as required (i.e. it does not have a `?`) it means it must be defined:

```
type SpriteProps = {
 sprites: {}
 name: string
 loading: boolean
}

// This is incorrect
// SpriteProps is saying all properties are required
// But right now `prop.name` for example is not
const prop: SpriteProps = {};
```

If you must populate things after you've defined the type, you need to make the fields optional. You can do either one of these two:

```
type SpriteProps = {
 sprites?: {}
 name?: string
 loading?: boolean
}

// This is fine now
const prop: SpriteProps = {};
```

or

```
type SpriteProps = {
 sprites: {}
 name: string
 loading: boolean
}

// This is fine now
const prop: Partial<SpriteProps> = {};
```

Another option is to create an object with empty values for these fields:

```
type SpriteProps = {
 sprites: {}
 name: string
 loading: boolean
}

// This is fine now
const prop: Partial<SpriteProps> = {
  sprites: {},
  name: '',
  loading: true,
};
```